# Prevent require.js to log itself to console

Tags: javascript, requirejs

When I run this code in Chrome DevTool,

```
require(['common'], function (common) { common.getProfilPic(123); })
```

It always print the whole chunk of ***requirejs*** code,

```
function localRequire(deps, callback, errback) {
                    var id, map, requireMod;

                    if (options.enableBuildCallback && callback && isFunction(callback)) {
                        callback.__requireJsBuild = true;
                    }

                    if (typeof deps === 'string') {
                        if (isFunction(callback)) {
                            //Invalid call
                            return onError(makeError('requireargs', 'Invalid require call'), errback);
                        }

                        //If require|exports|module are requested, get the
                        //value for them from the special handlers. Caveat:
                        //this only works while module is being defined.
                        if (relMap && hasProp(handlers, deps)) {
                            return handlers[deps](registry[relMap.id]);
                        }

                        //Synchronous access to one module. If require.get is
                        //available (as in the Node adapter), prefer that.
                        if (req.get) {
                            return req.get(context, deps, relMap, localRequire);
                        }

                        //Normalize module name, if it contains . or ..
                        map = makeModuleMap(deps, relMap, false, true);
                        id = map.id;

                        if (!hasProp(defined, id)) {
                            return onError(makeError('notloaded', 'Module name "' +
                                        id +
                                        '" has not been loaded yet for context: ' +
                                        contextName +
                                        (relMap ? '' : '. Use require([])')));
                        }
                        return defined[id];
                    }

                    //Grab defines waiting in the global queue.
                    intakeDefines();

                    //Mark all the dependencies as needing to be loaded.
                    context.nextTick(function () {
                        //Some defines could have been added since the
                        //require call, collect them.
                        intakeDefines();

                        requireMod = getModule(makeModuleMap(null, relMap));

                        //Store if map config should be applied to this require
                        //call for dependencies.
                        requireMod.skipMap = options.skipMap;

                        requireMod.init(deps, callback, errback, {
                            enabled: true
                        });

                        checkLoaded();
                    });

                    return localRequire;
                } require.js:1361
require(['common'], function (common) { console.log(common.getProfilPic(123)); })
function localRequire(deps, callback, errback) {
                    var id, map, requireMod;

                    if (options.enableBuildCallback && callback && isFunction(callback)) {
                        callback.__requireJsBuild = true;
                    }

                    if (typeof deps === 'string') {
                        if (isFunction(callback)) {
                            //Invalid call
                            return onError(makeError('requireargs', 'Invalid require call'), errback);
                        }

                        //If require|exports|module are requested, get the
                        //value for them from the special handlers. Caveat:
                        //this only works while module is being defined.
                        if (relMap && hasProp(handlers, deps)) {
                            return handlers[deps](registry[relMap.id]);
                        }

                        //Synchronous access to one module. If require.get is
                        //available (as in the Node adapter), prefer that.
                        if (req.get) {
                            return req.get(context, deps, relMap, localRequire);
                        }

                        //Normalize module name, if it contains . or ..
                        map = makeModuleMap(deps, relMap, false, true);
                        id = map.id;

                        if (!hasProp(defined, id)) {
                            return onError(makeError('notloaded', 'Module name "' +
                                        id +
                                        '" has not been loaded yet for context: ' +
                                        contextName +
                                        (relMap ? '' : '. Use require([])')));
                        }
                        return defined[id];
                    }

                    //Grab defines waiting in the global queue.
                    intakeDefines();

                    //Mark all the dependencies as needing to be loaded.
                    context.nextTick(function () {
                        //Some defines could have been added since the
                        //require call, collect them.
                        intakeDefines();

                        requireMod = getModule(makeModuleMap(null, relMap));

                        //Store if map config should be applied to this require
                        //call for dependencies.
                        requireMod.skipMap = options.skipMap;

                        requireMod.init(deps, callback, errback, {
                            enabled: true
                        });

                        checkLoaded();
                    });

                    return localRequire;
                }
```

and and me from seeing the log result, and idea how to stop requirejs to print itself?

Answer (score 0):

Run this instead:

```
(function(){ require(['common'], function (common) { common.getProfilPic(123); }) })()
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the console is printing out the value of the expression. The value of a function call is what the call returns. You can easily work around it with something like:

```
require(['common'], function (common) { common.getProfilPic(123); }); 1
```

Adding `; 1` will make the expression evaluate to 1. So you'll get `1` on the console but at least it won't push diagnostic messages off the screen.